# "WebRTC>Allow Media Capture on Insecure Sites" for iOS?

Tags: ios, webrtc, mobile-safari

As of Safari 11, the desktop has a useful devtool that overrides restrictions to allow WebRTC on non-HTTPS sites:

[image]

I've been looking for a way to do something similar for the iOS version of Safari. but can't find anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable WebRTC on insecure origins by opening the iOS device web inspector window in Mac Safari clicking on the "document icon" to the far right on the top, (to the left of the search bar), near the "crosshair" icon.

[Source](https://webkit.org/blog/9454/changing-page-settings-on-ios-using-web-inspector/)